Setting Up a "Pwnmachine" Bug Bounty Server Using the YesWeHack Tool
I'm exploring the implementation of a bug bounty program and came across the "Pwnmachine" tool by YesWeHack, which seems promising for setting up a bug bounty server. I'm aiming to establish a robust infrastructure for managing vulnerabilities and facilitating collaboration between security researchers and our team.
Following the YesWeHack Pwnmachine Installation Guide, I've encountered some technical challenges.
While trying to run the docker-compose up --build -d  command I get this error
Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on [::1]:53: read udp [::1]:37419->[::1]:53: read: connection refused

Here's what I've tried so far:
sudo systemctl restart docker
sudo docker-compose up --build -d

But it's still not working. Any suggestions on how to resolve this?
DNS Configuration: Once I get Pwnmachine up and running, how do I point my DNS records from my domain purchased through GoDaddy to the bug bounty server?
enter image description here
I tried to set it up using this Python-pip package and was faced with errors in the pictures attached
